# Dropping columns from data.frame that contain "null"

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a multiple data.frames that are similar to dat, where A is numeric and B is factor:

```
A,B
1,null
2,null
3,null
```

I would like to drop all columns that contain only “null”. I have tried many solutions, including:

```
dat[, !apply(dat == "null", 2, all)]

Error in `[.data.frame`(newdat, , !apply(dat == "null", 2, all)) : 
  undefined columns selected

dat %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.null)

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `B` is of unsupported type NULL
```

Other solutions give similar errors (most give the "undefined columns" error). I would like to do this without calling the columns by name or number. Thanks!

Comment: Can you `dput` a sample of your data frame `dat` so we can work on your data? I think the problem is with the word "null" which R treats as a character string, but want to verify.

Comment: `df[sapply(df,function(x) !all(sapply(x,is.null)))]` ?

Comment: dat <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "null", class = "factor"), 
    B = c(6.45597297196173, 6.45597297196173, 6.45597297196173, 
    6.45597297196173, 6.45597297196173)), .Names = c("A", "B"
), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: (I think that's what you're looking for @mysteRious? Thanks!)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper this didn't give an error but also didn't do anything to the df :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, `dat[, !apply(dat == "null", 2, all), drop = FALSE]` works just fine. Note the argument `drop = FALSE`. I have tried it with the dataset in the question and with the dataset in the comment, the results were as expected. No errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values in columns are as `null` (lower case) then one possible solution can be as:

```
df[,colSums(df=="null")!=nrow(df)]
```

For the data from OP:

```
dat[,apply(dat, 2, function(x)any(!as.character(x)=="null")), drop = FALSE]
# B
# 1 6.455973
# 2 6.455973
# 3 6.455973
# 4 6.455973
# 5 6.455973
```

**Data**

```
dat <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "null", class = "factor"), 
        B = c(6.45597297196173, 6.45597297196173, 6.45597297196173, 6.45597297196173, 6.45597297196173)), 
        .Names = c("A", "B" ), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This gives the error: Error in `[.data.frame`(newdat, , colSums(newdat == "null") != nrow(newdat)) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: @Mollie Try second solution, That is specific to your `data.frame`.

Comment: thanks, the second solution worked! (I am unable to upvote it)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative `dplyr` solution:

```
dat <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "null", class = "factor"), 
                      B = c(6.45597297196173, 6.45597297196173, 6.45597297196173, 6.45597297196173, 6.45597297196173)), 
                 .Names = c("A", "B" ), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame") 

library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  summarise_all(function(x) sum(x[!is.na(x)] == "null") == length(x[!is.na(x)])) %>% # check if number of nulls is equal to number of rows after removing NAs
  select_if(function(x) x == FALSE) %>%       # select columns that don't have only nulls
  names() -> vars_to_keep                     # keep column names

dat %>% select(vars_to_keep)                  # select columns captured above

#   B
# 1 6.455973
# 2 6.455973
# 3 6.455973
# 4 6.455973
# 5 6.455973
```

Comment: Thanks! I like dplyr solutions but this gives the error: Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'NA' not found

Comment: Is that error on the example dataset (my code)? Or when you try to apply it to your full dataset?

Comment: It's an error on my full dataset. Someone noted above that they couldn't reproduce the error on the sample dataset I provided, and I'm not sure why, so I suppose this isn't a good reproducible example. Unfortunately I can't share the full dataset because it's census microdata.

Comment: Hmmm. Any chance you have NA values in your columns? I might need to modify my code.

Comment: Yes, there are NA values in some columns, that's probably the issue! But not in the columns that contain "null".

Comment: Yes this works very quickly! Thanks! I haven't decided which answer I'm going to keep in my function, but when I do I'll accept that answer. Otherwise I would upvote but i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant, but still readable:

```
> dat[dat=="null"]<-NA_character_
> dat <- dat[,colSums(is.na(dat))<nrow(dat)]
> dat
[1] 6.455973 6.455973 6.455973 6.455973 6.455973
```